# Using old style access token with SSO FBDialog?

Tags: ios, facebook, access-token, fbdialogs

I've an application, that has old style facebook access_tokens (something like "*APPID|xyeahsfa-123465683821.---...*" ) and an iOS App using the current facebook SDK (with SSO). 
Using

```
 Facebook *facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:appId];
 facebook.accessToken = accessToken;
 facebook.expirationDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
 [facebook dialog:@"feed" 
       andDelegate:self];
```

i'm trying to show the User a dialog to post something to facebook. However, this fails with an "An eroor occured with application XY" error. The Error URL I saw said something about "no session cookie to validate against" with errno 110.
With a "new" access token, one that I got from the Single Sign On DemoApp, works just fine.

Has anybody expierenced this or any clue how to work around it?

Answer (score 1):

From your source it looks like you are missing the auth step:

```
Facebook* facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:appId];
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

Comment: i'm not using sso, but "old style" oauth authentification using https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=12xxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=user_photos,email&type=user_agent